# Nifi SQL connection error: Unable to execute SQL Query EET Error

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, apache-nifi

I am quite new in Apache products.

I am trying to retrieve data from MS SQL with Nifi(1.11.4) but I got below error:

> EET ERROR QueryDatabaseTable[id=08bsaha-0175-1000-c2871-af278378fa817]
> Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM PassCount due to
> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory(The
> Connection to the host server_name='STI04, named instance sql2014'
> failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: server_name='STI04".
> Verify the server and instan names and check that no firewall is
> blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later,
> verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the
> host.):org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException

Here is other info about the connection:

> DBCPConnectionPool

```
Database Connection URL: jdbc:sqlserver://server_name=STI04\SQL2014;database=Sales

Database Driver Class Name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Database Driver Location(s): C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 8.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_8.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar
```

> QueryDatabaseTable

```
Database Connection Pooling Service: DBCPConnectionPool
Database Type: MS SQL 2012+
Table Name: PassCount
```

Below picture is the how it looks on NiFi

[image]

I guess it may be because of 'STI04\SQL2014' notation in connection URL.
I already checked firewall and there is no issue about it.

How can I solve this?
Also it doesn't have to be same processors.
I just want to get data from SQL and see this queue filling up. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation yet, [Named and multiple SQL Server instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#named-and-multiple-sql-server-instances)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root error is actually this:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: server_name='STI04".`

It looks like a JDBC networking issue. It cannot resolve the hostname from the information you provided.